# next() of jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

When first tile is selected L3 should work how L2 works. I tried to selected that using `next()` of jQuery but it's not working. [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9PWRS/)

```html
<nav id="lastNavigation" class="d row clearfix">
  <aside class="col-xs-11">
    <div class="col-xs-12 lessonNavigation lesson">
      <header>LESSONS (3 of 10)<span class="tilesToggle">[+] See All</span></header>
      <article class="arrowButton mr10"><a href="#" class="icon icon-arrow-left active" type="button"></a></article>
      <ul class="expandable">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#"><span>L1<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#"> <span>L2<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#"> <span>L3<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#"> <span>L4<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#"><span>L5<b>: Recognize a digit represents 10 times the value</b></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <article class="arrowButton ml10">
        <a href="#" class="icon icon-arrow-right active" type="button"></a>
      </article>
    </div>
  </aside>
</nav>
```

jQuery goes here

```js
if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')) {
  $('.icon-arrow-left').toggleClass('inactive active');
  $(this).next().next().click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('text');
  });
}
```

Comment: there is a lot of code... what are you really trying to do

Comment: I'm talking about the jquery code that is given in question. here $(this).next().next() isn't working.

Comment: The condition `$('li:first-child').hasClass('activeLesson')` is always false

Comment: The problem is in that context `this` refers to the `icon-arrow-right` element, which does not have a next sibling